# Lemma 2.6.5 from Kempf's Algebraic Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm really struggling to understand this lemma, stating that:

> let $X$ be an irreducible affine variety. If $g$ is a non-zero regular function on $X$ such that $\dim (g=0)\leq \dim (X)-2$, then $g$ is a unit in $K[X]$.

There are two main steps I'm not convinced about.

The first one is the use of so-called "preparation lemma" to say that there's a finite, surjective morphism $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb A^n$. The book proved that given any non zero-polynomial $i$ in $K[\mathbb A^n]$, there's a finite surhective morphism between $\{i=0\}$ and $\mathbb A^{n-1}$, but I don't clearly see how to use this. I feel like a similar proof is needed, but I can't conclude.

The second one is the fact that a morphism of the form $x \mapsto (f(x),g(x))$ between $X$ and $\mathbb A^{n+1}$ is finite if $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb A^n$ is a finite moprhism.